# Cannot run MySql image on Docker - Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run a MySQL image on Docker, but i'm getting the following error:

```
PS D:\Desktop\JC\personal\flow-api> docker compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container flow-api-db-1             Created                                                                     0.0s
 ✔ Container flow-api-cognito-local-1  Recreated                                                                   0.2s
Attaching to cognito-local, flow-api-db-1
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15 20:48:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15 20:48:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15 20:48:33+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.flow-api-db-1  | '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
cognito-local  | [1702673313425] INFO: NONE NONE Cognito Local running on http://0.0.0.0:9229
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:33.570589Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:33.576459Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 1
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:33.581536Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:33.620662Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:34.077216Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012960] [InnoDB] Cannot create redo log files because data files are corrupt or the database was not shut down cleanly after creating the data files.
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:34.077274Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:34.401729Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:34.401956Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:34.402028Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
flow-api-db-1  | 2023-12-15T20:48:34.403020Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.35)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
flow-api-db-1 exited with code 1
```

I tried to delete the container, the image and the volumes and creating it again, also tried to run it with docker-compose instead of docker compose but isn't working neither.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  cognito-local:
    container_name: cognito-local
    image: jagregory/cognito-local:latest
    ports:
      - 9229:9229
    volumes:
      - .cognito:/app/.cognito

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT}:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql
```

My folder structure is

- docker-compose.yml
- data/mysql/LOT_OF_MYSQL_FILES

I'm using `> Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128`